# CircleCI configuration to deploy to server

Tags: php, linux, circleci

**Question:**

Could anyone tell me why the below configuration is not working?

**Error:**

Error: orb not found: scp _r * shinedom@shinedome.com:

**Config:**

```
# PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-php/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/php:7.1.5-browsers

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mysql:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - scp -r * shinedom@shinedome.com:/home/shinedom/public_html
```